Как правильно использовать StateFlow для обновления UIState экрана
Попалась мне вот такая статья
https://proandroiddev.com/loading-initial-data-in-launchedeffect-vs-viewmodel-f1747c20ce62
в которой автор описывая преймущества и недостатки подходов инициализации данных приходит к тому, что лучше всего делать это через StateFlow. Я решил попросбовать сделать это, при условии того, что я использую UiState обертку как общий стейт для экрана:
sealed class UiState<out T> {
    object Loading : UiState<Nothing>()
    data class Error(val code: Int? = null, val message: String? = null) : UiState<Nothing>()
    data class Content<T>(val data: T) : UiState<T>()
}

то есть моя имплементация до изменений:
class MyRepo {
    fun getMyData(): Flow<List<String>> {
        return flow {
            delay(1000)
            emit(listOf("1", "2"))
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel1(repo: MyRepo): ViewModel() {
    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val title: String = "Title"
    )

    private val _screenUiState: MutableStateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> = MutableStateFlow(UiState.Loading)
    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> = _screenUiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.getMyData()
                .map<List<String>, UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { UiState.Content(ScreenStateUI(data = it)) }
                .collectLatest {
                    if (it is UiState.Content) {
                        _screenUiState.emit(
                            UiState.Content(data = it)
                        )
                }
        }
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        _screenUiState.update {
            if (it is UiState.Content) {
                it.copy(data = it.data.copy(title = title))
            } else {
                it
            }
        }
    }
}

При инициализации подгружается стейт и UI может подписаться на изменения через screenUiState, то есть если нужно использовать fun updateTitle(title: String) то нет никаких проблем.
Теперь я поменял имплемантацию, чтоб избавиться от инициализиции в init блоке и сделать все как только UI подписывается на ивент:
    class MyRepo {
        fun getMyData(): Flow<List<String>> {
            return flow {
                delay(1000)
                emit(listOf("1", "2"))
            }
        }
    }

class MyViewModel2(repo: MyRepo): ViewModel() {
    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String> = emptyList(),
        val title: String = "Title"
    )

    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> by lazy {
        repo.getMyData()
            .map<List<String>, UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { UiState.Content(ScreenStateUI(data = it)) }
            .onStart { emit(UiState.Loading) }
            .catch { emit(UiState.Error(message = it.message)) }
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                initialValue = UiState.Loading
            )
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        ...
    }
}

то есть вроде все выглядит не плохо и действительно теперь UI запустит запросы только когда подпишется, но теперь стейт нельзя изменить, и соответственно метод fun updateTitle(title: String) не может обновить title.
Что я пропускаю здесь?

Как по мне, вы не поняли идею статьи. Переделали обычное property в computed property, пусть и lazy. А статья скорее о cold flow -> hot flow: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html

@EugeneKrivenja мне так не кажется, в статье автор рассуждает о том, как лучше делать init загрузку данных в итоге ссылаясь на Ian Lake, он говорит, что предпочтительнее использовать cold flow

в итоге вот такое решение получилось
class MyViewModel2(repo: MyRepo) : ViewModel() {
    private val titleFlow = MutableStateFlow("Title")

    data class ScreenStateUI(
        val data: List<String>,
        val title: String,
    )

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(2000)
            updateTitle(title = "New title")
        }
    }

    val screenUiState: StateFlow<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> by lazy {
        combine(
            repo.getMyData(),
            titleFlow,
        ) { data, title ->
            Log.e("HERE", "combine: $data :: $title")
            UiState.Content<ScreenStateUI>(ScreenStateUI(data = data, title = title))
        }
            .onStart<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { emit(UiState.Loading) }
            .catch<UiState<ScreenStateUI>> { emit(UiState.Error(message = it.message)) }
            .stateIn<UiState<ScreenStateUI>>(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                initialValue = UiState.Loading,
            )
    }

    fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        titleFlow.value = title
    }
}

Исполузуя `combine` можно сделать, то что нужно.


вы не можете обновить стейт, т.к. делаете преобразование stateIn + выбрали стратегию SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed
ваш первый вариант, является более корректным, т.к. стейт доступен для изменения внутри ВьюМодели.
в вашем примере, у вас есть стейт и вы слушаете какой-то флоу из репозитоиря.
а что если вам придется слушать 2 флоу из 2ух разных репозиториев? пример 2 уже начнет превращаться в большую конструкцию с подводными камнями.
да и я бы сказал что идея "ВьюМодель выполняет запросы, только когда на нее подписаны" слегка противоречит основной идеи ВьюМодели "жить независимо от ЖЦ экрана"
мне до конца не ясно "что именно вы хотите изменить в своем коде (пример 1) и для чего?"

Мне в целом нравиться подход в первом примере, но решил попробовать подход описанный автором в статье, так как там говорится о том, что cold flow лучше подходит, одно из преймуществ это то, что VM начинает выполнять запросы тогда когда есть подписчик и останавливает логику когда подписчика нет, все автоматически. Когда VM выполняет инициализацию в init блоке, у тебя нет возможности создать VM отдельно от UI, так как в таком случае ты бы не хотел, чтоб VM выполняло логику без подписчика.

@Sirop4ik это очень спорно. ведь отсутствие подписчика не означает, что логика должна останавливаться. например, открыл новый фрагмент, а текущий остался в бэкстеке. подписчиков нет, а вот логика должна продолжать работать (например, запросы на сервер каждый 5 секунд). так же не забывайте о том, что если подписчик пропадет и подключиться опять, то со стратегией WhileSubscribed вы опять будете делать всю работу заново.

согласен, это наверное тонкости имплементации, но как по мне если речь идет о UiState то подразумевается, что это стейт экрана, то что должен видеть юзер, если нет экрана, то и стейт не нужен. В случае с запросами на сервер - это наверное лучше сделать какой то менеджер который будет это делать, а не UiState. Насчет WhileSubscribed там специально стоит 5 секунд задержка на удаление кэша, если допустим смена конфигурации или еще что то, то есть 5 секунд на переподписаться и юзер запрос не будет выполняться заново

@Sirop4ik UIState никак не связан ни с какими менеджерами, запросами, бд и тд и тп. UIState - это описание состояния экрана. он является горячим потоком, лишь потому что постоянно может изменяться и его текущее состояние должно быть всегда доступным. вы можете слушать данные из менеджеров в зависимости от состояние экрана (onPause, onResume) и отправлять их в UIState.
